# Building a new dataframe of affiliations based on common variables in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I don't know if I worded my question properly but I will describe below.

Given a dataframe such as:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| A    | z    |
| B    | z    |
| C    | z    |
| A    | x    |
| D    | x    |
+------+------+
```

I want to output a dataframe with affilitations between col 1 variables that share common col2 variables

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
| A    | C    |
| C    | B    |
| A    | D    |
+------+------+
```

As you can see, the col1 variables that shared common Col2 variables with other Col1 variables are now affiliated in the second dataframe.

I haven't come across a way to automate this and would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Hi, why is there no B:C and D:A in your second frame, or why is it C:B and not B:C?

Comment: I am trying to build a network, so I am unsure if I need duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  Col1 = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D'),
  Col2 = c('z', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'x')
) %>%
  split(.$Col2) %>%
  map_dfr(~ combn(.x$Col1, 2) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame())
```